# Какие есть функции сравнения строк в jquery?

Tags: jquery

Пример: для поиска задается набор символов "но", из слов пианино, нота, корона, должны выбраться пианино и нота. Причем символы для поиска берутся из переменной.

Как можно реализовать такое на jQuery? Есть ли подобные функции?

Comment: Очень информативный ответ, поражающий глубиной содержащихся в нем мыслей.

Comment: А самому написать - не? =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function searchText( string, needle ) {
   return !!(string.search( needle ) + 1);
}

var text = 'но';
console.log(searchText('пианино', text)); // -> true
console.log(searchText('нота', text));    // -> true
console.log(searchText('корона', text));  // -> false
```

Comment: какой интересный способ приведения

Comment: не знал о таком. но просили же на jQuery, вот я и извратился :D

Comment: @exec - так а что кроме `each` вы взяли из jQ? (вопрос риторический)

И я не буду утверждать, но по-моему indexOf не работает в IE (причем, по-моему, даже для массива)

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = ['пианино', 'нота', 'корона'],
    find = 'но',
    newArray = [];
$.each(array, function (index, value) {
  if( value.indexOf(find) != -1 ) {
    newArray.push(value);
  }
});
console.log(newArray.join(', ')); // пианино, нота
```